# How do I extract a value from a Linq IQueryable object?

Tags: vb.net, linq, vb.net-2010

I am new to Linq and have been stumped for several days. I have searched this and several other boards to find the answer but cannot. I have a Linq query that is returning 1 value of int.

```
Public Function myV()
    Dim MR As New MainEntities()
    Dim mV = From AspNetUsers In MR.AspNetUsers
                Where Context.User.Identity.Name() = AspNetUsers.Email.ToString Select AspNetUsers.VB
    Return mV
End Function

If myV = 1 Then
perform other code
End If
```

But when I try to compare to an Int it says the object cannot be compared. I have tried to convert the IQueryable(of Interger) to Int and cannot. How do I get to the Interger value in the IQueryable object?

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ statement returns an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), which is like an array in that it can hold multiple values, even it only happens to have one value in it.

The best way to return a single value is [`.First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx), or [`.Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) if you want to throw an exception if more than one value exists. (Which one you choose depends on your context.)

```
Public Function myV()
    Dim MR As New MainEntities()
    Dim mV = From AspNetUsers In MR.AspNetUsers
                Where Context.User.Identity.Name() = AspNetUsers.Email.ToString Select AspNetUsers.VB.First()
    Return mV
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `mV` is an `IQueryable`, you can consider it as a type of list or an array. So you need to get the first value:

```
If myV.First() = 1 Then
    '...
End If
```

Or more likely you want to do that inside the `mV` function:

```
Dim mV = From AspNetUsers In MR.AspNetUsers
         Where Context.User.Identity.Name() = AspNetUsers.Email.ToString
         Select AspNetUsers.VB
Return mV.First()
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the query. Your LINQ executes a SQL Statement that is the follows:

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.VB
FROM AspNetUsers
WHERE ApsNetUsers.Email = "here the name"
```

Therefore the query does not return only one `VB` but a table consisting of one column and multiple rows.

In order to retrieve the first value you have to call `.First()`

```
If myV.First() = 1 Then [...]
```